# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list c#

Tags: javascript, c#

it takes me too long to get what is wrong with the javascript function argument.
Something in the string is missing ?

```
message = "'La Persona : '" + list[0] + "' ha sido Ingresada'";   

public void MostrarMensaje(string message)
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript
        (GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: Mostrar("+ message +"); ", true);
} 

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function Mostrar(nom) {
          alert(nom);
      }
   </script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Tell us what you expecting and what you get. What you mean by `not working`?

Comment: i get in the chrome  developer console "Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list"..  

Without argument works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
message = "'La Persona : '" + list[0] + "' ha sido Ingresada'";
```

should be

```
message = "'La Persona : " + list[0] + " ha sido Ingresada'";
```

or if you mean to show them, escape them

```
message = "'La Persona : \'" + list[0] + "\' ha sido Ingresada'";
```